# Creation of ECPublicKey from a String

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, key, rsa

I have a normal String, I encode it using Base64 class from Java util and pass it in ECPublicKey constructor but its not working. Do we have to encode in some other format to pass it in ECPublicKey constructor?

I have tried creating keyfactory approach too, like below, the encoding obj is Base64-encoded String

```
byte[] keyBytesPublic = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodingObj);

X509EncodedKeySpec specPublic = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytesPublic);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
ECPublicKey public_key12 = (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(specPublic);

String obj = "{ "+
    "hello world "+
"}";

byte[] encodingObj = Base64.getEncoder().encode(obj.getBytes());
byte[] keyBytesPublic = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodingObj);
```

First tried generating from key fatory

```
X509EncodedKeySpec specPublic = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytesPublic);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
ECPublicKey public_key12 = (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(specPublic);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(specPublic);
```

or if i directly pass encoding obj in constructor

```
ECPublicKey publicKey1 = new ECPublicKeyImpl(encodingObj);
```

Comment: Need more details: (1) the sample input string, (2) the error message. Better yet, a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is called `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`, which is part of the X.509 specifications. It is an ASN.1 encoded structure that also includes the key type. Internally you would have an X9.63 structure encoding the public key. Within there you have the options of named curves (where curve parameters are identified using an OID) or curves specifying all of their parameters and uncompressed or compressed points for the public point W.

For instance, you can see an example using a named curve with OID and uncompressed public point [in this other question I answered](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63266/1172):

```
> openssl asn1parse -i -in ecpub.der -inform DER -dump
0:d=0  hl=2 l=  89 cons: SEQUENCE          
2:d=1  hl=2 l=  19 cons:  SEQUENCE          
4:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim:   OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
13:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :prime256v1
23:d=1  hl=2 l=  66 prim:  BIT STRING        
  0000 - 00 04 d0 ee 64 61 7b 90-48 a2 a9 5f b5 a3 da 67   ....da{.H.._...g
  0010 - 53 56 91 e0 cf 5b b8 85-3e 05 0c b9 e6 95 c3 8d   SV...[..>.......
  0020 - 26 ab d7 ee 47 94 38 61-1e cd 07 e6 90 0b 3d 4a   &...G.8a......=J
  0030 - 6a df c5 d5 9f f3 11 91-53 00 ff 0e 91 93 49 44   j.......S.....ID
  0040 - 4c 58
```

Note that I changed the line to use DER as that's what Java is expecting. Java doesn't contain a PEM parser in the public API, you'll have to use e.g. Bouncy Castle for that.

---

You should not generate a key using a key factory from scratch, keys are part of a public / private key *pair*. To create such an encoding you can use the following code (including base64 if you need a string):

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
kpg.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
System.out.println("Encoding format: " + publicKey.getFormat());
byte[] derEncoded = publicKey.getEncoded();
// base64 encoded is what you get for PEM, between the header and footer lines
String base64DEREncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(derEncoded);
System.out.println("Base64 SubjectPublicKeyInfo: " + base64DEREncoded);
```

Result:

```
Encoding format: X.509
Base64 SubjectPublicKeyInfo: MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEDA0qMRpJwaJyJ4YDciMqWefvr/mwYvF1fKnblJl5DOqAh5XUXkdWvYRDTTs9hPoHfPaNWWC9I0hOGb6+JPNxVw==
```

---

Of course, you generally want to store the private key somewhere secure as well, e.g. in a key store.